# Header 2 text does not match the exact same text in excel : VBA

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, ms-word

I am creating a project that lets the user create a task list within excel and then compares the user created tasks-text to the second header-text, (Header 2) within a pre-made word document. I am able to get the second header text and save it to an array, and then get the user task list and save that within an array. I then try and see if the task text that is within the Program (The second headers) are within the user task list using the function

```
    If IsError(Application.Match(ProgArray(x), TaskArray, 0)) Then
        'Find within word document and highlight red
    End if
```

The problem I am getting is that this always returns with an error because for some reason, even though the built in watch screen debugger says otherwise, the text within the word document does not equal the exact same text within the excel sheet.

At first I used a comparing text software to determine that the header's text from word might have actually copied an extra line. 
Picture of explanation: [image: example here]

But then I tried to trim, and check for whether or not the header text had vbNewLine

```
    If Right$(StrFound, 2) = vbCrLf Or Right$(StrFound, 2) = vbNewLine Then
```

Also to no avail, as this if statement was never triggered.

My question is, is taking text from a word document also pulling some hidden value that I am just missing, and if so is there any way around this? Thank you and sorry for the wall of text.

Lastly here is my complete code: (Its not pretty as I am just going for functionality right now)

```
'Sub CheckHeader()
Dim blnFound As Boolean
Dim StrFound As String
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer
Dim TaskTotal As Integer
Dim ProgArray(149) As String
Dim TaskArray() As String
Dim NotInArray() As String
Dim NotInProg() As String
Dim appWd As Object
Dim TaskSheet As Worksheet

Set appWd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set wdFind = appWd.Selection.Find
Set TaskSheet = Sheets("Task List")

'Get Task List from Excel
TaskTotal = TaskSheet.Cells(TaskSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
ReDim TaskArray(TaskTotal) As String
ReDim NotInProg(TaskTotal) As String
ReDim NotInArray(TaskTotal) As String

'Get User task list into an array to compare - 0 to 0 is for testing
For x = 0 To 0 'TaskTotal - 1
    TaskArray(x) = TaskSheet.Cells(2 + x, 5).Value '+ " (" & TaskSheet.Cells(2 + x, 1).Value + " " _
        & TaskSheet.Cells(2 + x, 3).Value + ": " & TaskSheet.Cells(2 + x, 4).Value + ")"
Next x

x = 0
y = 0
'Find all instances of Headings
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    '.Text = "Test"
    .Style = "Heading 2"

    Do
        blnFound = .Execute
        If blnFound Then
            'MsgBox .Parent.Text
            StrFound = .Parent.Text
            'StrFound = Right(StrFound, InStr(StrFound, ")") + 1)
            StrFound = CStr(StrFound)
            TaskSheet.Cells(2 + x, 120).Value = StrFound
            'At first I thought it was also saving a new line but I couldn't get rid of it
            If Right$(StrFound, 2) = vbCrLf Or Right$(StrFound, 2) = vbNewLine Then
            z = 1
            End If
            ProgArray(x) = TaskSheet.Cells(2 + x, 120)
            'StrFound
            x = x + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    End With

       'Compare if List is in Program
     For x = 0 To 149
    If x < TaskTotal - 1 Then
        If IsError(Application.Match(TaskArray(x), ProgArray, 0)) Then
            NotInProg(y) = TaskArray(x)
            y = y + 1
        End If
    End If

    'If the header is not within the user created task list then run this case
    If IsError(Application.Match(ProgArray(x), TaskArray, 0)) Then
        'used for debugging, for some reason the header text is larger than the user text
        MsgBox StrComp(ProgArray(x), TaskArray(x))

        NotInArray(z) = ProgArray(x)
        SearchName = NotInArray(z)
        'Increase element
        z = z + 1
        'Check Program and highlight to show that what is in the program is not in the user task list
        With wdFind
            .Text = SearchName
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute
        End With
        If wdFind.Found Then
            'MsgBox " Found it"
            appWd.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
        Else
            MsgBox ProgArray(x) + " is not in TaskList"
        End If
    Else
        'Otherwise it is in the program and if it was red, unhighlight the text
        SearchName = TaskArray(x)
        With wdFind
            .Text = SearchName
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute
        End With
        If wdFind.Found Then
            'MsgBox " Found it"
            appWd.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight

            ' For not in task Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed

            ' For not in prog Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Else
            MsgBox TaskArray(x) + " is not here"
        End If
    End If

     'Lastly Check for Ordering

     Next x

     End Sub'
```

Comment: Did you try to cut the last mark of found range in Word?? try to put this line: `.Parent.SetRange .Parent.Start, .Parent.End - 1` just before: `StrFound = .Parent.Text`

Comment: The .Parent.Text is indeed the problem, and your input actually fixed the new line issue, but now I can't cycle through the sheet as its range is stuck on the first thing it finds. Not a fan of Word haha. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to add `.Parent.MoveEnd` right after `x=x+1` inside your `do...loop`.

Comment: Oh my dear sweet baby Jesus. Thank you, this fixes everything and keeps me from dealing with my new jumbled work around that is making me want to jab myself with the pointiest of sticks.

Comment: Yes indeed, I am still new to StackOverFlow So how do I credit you for solving the question?

Comment: could you please mark this question as solved once again. The previous answer was deleted as incomplete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems within your code and solutions to them are as follows:

1. To cut new paragraph mark we need to cut it of in this way:

   ```
   .Parent.SetRange .Parent.Start, .Parent.End - 1
   ```

   Which you need to put just before:

   ```
   StrFound = .Parent.Text
   ```
2. Additionally, add `.Parent.MoveEnd` right after `x=x+1` inside your `do...loop`.

Comment: +1 nice one ;). I'd love to see you join in on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175743/answer-marked-but-points-to-a-comment-s and share your perspective...